# How to combine Excel web addin and customfunction?

Tags: excel, visual-studio-code, office-js, yeoman, custom-functions-excel

Visual studio 19 allows to build an Excel web addin but, apparently, not custom function
Yeoman office provides vscode projects for both, separately, but not for the combination of the two.

How is it possible to build a combination of a web addin project combined and a custom function ?
(typescript would be prefered)

Answer (score 0):

In a second thought, a workaround could be to build two complements one for the Excel addin and the other for the custom functions. It's not totaly user friendly but should make it, if it's possible to use those two complement at the same time

Comment: You can modify the Excel Web addin project to add Custom Functions functionalities in the project. You can refer to the page of Create custom functions in Excel: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview

Comment: Unable to do that. If you could share the full code for it I would be very happy. With Visual Studio I am unable to insert the 'Enabled' elements (system fires a "invalid child" warning.